# Python to find out, from coordinates of non- habitable areas to location/address

Tags: python, google-maps, geolocation

Hello all… my question is regarding how to find out the location of a pair of geographical coordinates. Sorry the questions are fragmented because I did some searches and putting them together still doesn't find the right way.

**1st** question:
Seems Geopy is the best way to geocoding, if some outputs in non-English words is not a matter. (any help is warmly welcome for solving the non-English output problem)

However some of coordinates I need to search is in non- habitable areas.

An example below:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim()
location = geolocator.reverse("81.79875708, -42.1875")
print(location.address)
```

It returns.

```
None
```

When search this coordinates on https://maps.google.com/, it indicates the nearest recognized point “Northeast Greenland National Park”, which is better than “None”.

So how can I get this “nearest recognized point”?

**2nd** question on using “pygmaps”

```
aamap = pygmaps.maps(81.79875708, -42.1875, 16)
```

the output is:

```
<pygmaps.maps instance at 0x000000000313CC08>
```

What’s the use of it, and how to turn it into texts?

**3rd** question using the “Json” way:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA')
js  = json.load(response)
print js['results'][0]['geometry']['location']
```

Is there a way to reverse? i.e. using coordinates to find out its addresses.

Thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer to add more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot answer all your questions but, regarding your second question I suppose that you made use of `print(aamap)` to get the output.
The default behavior when printing an object that doesn't specify a way to be print is to print its class and its memory location. That is the result you obtained.

```
<pymaps.maps instance at 0x0000000000313CC08>
```

Test this code to understand :

```
class NotPrintable(object):
    def __init__(self, text):
        """ Instanciation method """
        self.text = text

class Printable(object):
    def __init__(self, text):
        """ Instanciation method """
        self.text = text

    def __repr__(self):
        """ Text representation of the object called by print"""
        return "A printable object whose the value is : {0}".format(self.text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print( NotPrintable("StackOverFlowTest") )
    print( Printable("StackOverFlowTest") )
```

The result is :

```
<__main__.NotPrintable object at 0x7f2e644fe208>
A printable object whose the value is : StackOverFlowTest
```

The result you get indicate that you are not supposed to print the item to visualize its content. A quick search on "google" lead me to this site : https://code.google.com/p/pygmaps/
It provides example of code using pymaps, and it appear that the good way to visualize the data is :

```
#create the map object
mymap = pygmaps.maps(37.428, -122.145, 16)
#export the map
mymap.draw('./mymap.html')
```

That create an HTML page that contain your map.
If interested in, you could take a look at the maps code at https://code.google.com/p/pygmaps/source/browse/trunk/pygmaps.py but it seems that it is the only way to output the object data. If you really have to provide a text output, you'll probably have to code the export by yourself.

Hope it helps!

=====EDIT=====

Concerning the googlemap JSON API, seeing the documentation : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

You can find in the first lines information about Reverse geocoding, i.e.

> The process of [...] translating a location on the map into a human-readable address, is known as reverse geocoding.

See this particulary : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

here is an example of query for information about the location whose the latitude is "40.71" and the longitude is "-73.96" :

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.71,-73.96&key=API_KEY
```

Here is the documentation about API_key : https://developers.google.com/console/help/#UsingKeys

Comment: no problem. Do not hesitate to ask for more information if some point are not understandable. I'm curious about the solutions you will retain. Even if not coming from me.

Comment: thanks for the follow-up, Arthur Vaïsse. by the way, how to find out my API_KEY? the google dashboard is changed...

Comment: Add reference to the documentation of API key.